# calling the parent controller function in Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: extjs, view, controller, scope

I have a login Page which authenticates the user.On correct username and password it should hide the loginview and display the next view.When I call the function to do the same  it gives an error saying `"Uncaught TypeError: this.functionname is not a function`.Here is my code for the same:

```
    startMain : function() {
    Eits.store.DataStore.init();
    Eits.Factory.getAppController().start();
    },
    doLoginClicked : function() {
    console.log("button pressed this time");
    var name = this.view.getUsername();
    var pass = this.view.getPassword();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(pass);

        Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'login/getLoginStatus.action',
        method:'post',
        params: {
            user: name,
            password: pass
            }
            ,
            success: function(response) {

                console.log(response);

                var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                var nextObj=obj.data;
                console.log(nextObj);
                if (nextObj[0].success) {

                      console.log(nextObj[0].msg);
                    this.startMain();//Uncaught TypeError: this.startMain is not a function
                    this.view.hide();//
                    }
                else
                    {
                    console.log(nextObj[0].msg);    
                    }

            },
            failure: function(response,options,success) {
                console.log("inside failure");
                console.log(response);
                console.log(options);
                console.log(success);
                  Ext.Msg.show({
                        title:'Error!',
                        msg: response.text,
                        icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                    });
                }
        });
    }
   }
```

Is there a way to call the functions and bypass this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope issue. When you call `this` in the success callback, you're not at the same scope where the `startMain` function is defined.

One solution is to declare a reference to the correct scope right inside the `doLoginClicked` function:

```
doLoginClicked : function () {
var me = this;
console.log("button pressed this time");
...
```

and then inside your Ajax success callback, you can replace `this` with `me`:

```
me.startMain();
```

Comment: @cpasstore84 Thanks ,it worked.I was trying to use xtype as well as scope ,but outside the `doLoginClicked`.

Thanks again!